# ¿ como generar un PDF con atributos de varios modelos y varias tablas de datos en Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, yii2

Necesito generar un archivo PDF con información de varios modelos y varias tablas de la Base de datos, que por medio de las llaves foráneas traiga la información relacionada con el ID y todo quede en un solo PDF en Yii2.

Estoy usando la extensión de `robregomn` para pdf, por eso no puse código ya que lo que he intentado ha sido algo muy básico como los namespace, la relación `modelo.atributo`, pero siempre me pasa es que me busca es en el modelo donde estoy renderizando el PDF, pero nada me ha funcionado, no estoy solicitando código sino una ayuda de como lo podría hacer o un tutorial en internet ya que no he encontrado alguno.

---

Hice lo que el compañero [Enric Borrallo me indicó en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233481/78) pero me marca error anexo pantallazo y el código usado, ya el widget esta instalado:

```
public function actionPdf()
{     
// get your HTML raw content without any layouts or scripts
$content = $this->renderPartial('pdf1');

// setup kartik\mpdf\Pdf component
$pdf = new Pdf(
 [
    // set to use core fonts only
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, 
    // A4 paper format
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4, 
    // portrait orientation
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT, 
    // stream to browser inline
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER, 
    // your html content input
    'content' => $content,  
    // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
    // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting 
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
    // any css to be embedded if required
    'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
     // set mPDF properties on the fly
    'options' => ['title' => 'Krajee Report Title'],
     // call mPDF methods on the fly
    'methods' => [ 
        'SetHeader'=>['Krajee Report Header'], 
        'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
    ]
]);

// return the pdf output as per the destination setting
return $pdf->render(); 
}
```

protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Empresa::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

```
   throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
}

    protected function findModelp($id)
{
    if (($modelp = Personal::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $modelp;
    }

   throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Hice lo que el compañero [Enric Borrallo me indicó en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233481/78), lo tengo configurado asi

en el controlador de empresa tengo la acción del PDF asi

```
public function actionPdf($id)
{     
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $pdf = new Pdf([
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, // leaner size using standard fonts
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
    'content' => $this->renderPartial('pdf1', [
        'model'=>$this->findModel($id),
        'modelp'=>$this->findModelp($id),
        ]),
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
    'filename'=>'Ficha',
    'options' => [
        // any mpdf options you wish to set
    ],
    'methods' => [
        'SetTitle' => 'Ficha Acueducto - PDA',
        'SetSubject' => 'Generating PDF files via yii2-mpdf extension has never been easy',
        'SetHeader' => ['Ficha Acueducto - PDA||Generated On: ' . date("r")],
        'SetFooter' => ['|Page {PAGENO}|'],
        'SetAuthor' => 'Kartik Visweswaran',
        'SetCreator' => 'Kartik Visweswaran',
        'SetKeywords' => 'Krajee, Yii2, Export, PDF, MPDF, Output, Privacy, Policy, yii2-mpdf',
    ]
]);
return $pdf->render();
```

}

en la vista pdf1 que esta guardada en el view empresa esta asi
title = $model->nombre_empresa;
?>
--

## title) ?>

$model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'nombre_empresa',
            'foto',
            'telefono',
            'email:email',
            'natu_juridica',
            'limite_norte',
            'limite_sur',
            'limite_oriente',
            'limite_occidente',
            'n_suscriptores',
            'logo',
            'mision:ntext',
            'vision:ntext',
            'manual_funciones',
            'uso_agua',
            'tarifa_promedio',
            'periodo_cobro',
            'created_at',
            'created_by',
            'updated_at',
            'updated_by',
        ],
    ]) ?>
--

## title) ?>

$modelp,
        'attributes' => [
            'area',
            'cantidad',
            'tipo_vinculacion',
            'observaciones:ntext',
        ],
    ]) ?>

no se si deba crear un controller aparte solo para el PDF e invocar la Acción en el controller de empresa que es el principal en mi caso o asi como lo tengo es correcto

De antemano gracias

Anexo pantallazo del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este no es un sitio para solicitar código. Debes leer **https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask** y [edit] la pregunta con lo que has intentado.

Comment: Buena tarde gracias por contestar, lo que pasa es que necesito es una pista de como puedo invocar el otro modelo al archivos del Render que tengo en Yii2, estoy usando la extensión de robregomn para pdf, por eso no puse codigo ya que lo que he intentado ha sido algo muy basico como los namespace, la relación modelo.atributo, pero siempre me pasa es que me busca es en el modelo donde estoy renderizando el PDF, pero nada me ha funcionado, no estoy solicitando codigo sino una ayuda de como lo podria hacer o un tutorial en internet ya que no he encontrado alguno, de antemano gracias

Comment: Michael, agrega esta información en la pregunta - los comentarios son temporales.

Comment: vale gracias por tu consejo

Comment: Michael, con gusto. Por cierto, cuando quieras agregar información, debes **[edit] la pregunta** - ya que los otros espacios son para respuestas. Espero que encuentres la solución a tu problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día compañeros

Ya pude generar el PDF gracias a los consejos de ustedes.

Anexo el código que use en el `controller` y en el `view` para futuras referencias:

**Controller:**

```
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;

public function actionPdf()
    {
        $model = Empresa::findOne(1);
        $datos=[1,2,4,5];
        $content = $this->renderPartial('pdf1',[
            'model'=>$model,        
            'data'=>$datos,
            ]);    
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
        $pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, // leaner size using standard fonts
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        'content'=>$content,   
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        'filename'=>'Ficha',
        'options' => [
            // any mpdf options you wish to set
        ],
        'methods' => [
            'SetTitle' => 'Ficha Acueducto - PDA',
            'SetSubject' => 'Generating PDF files via yii2-mpdf extension has never been easy',
            'SetHeader' => ['Ficha Acueducto - PDA||Generado el: ' . date("r")],
            'SetFooter' => ['|Pagina {PAGENO}|'],
            'SetAuthor' => 'PDA - Caldas',
            'SetCreator' => 'PDA -Caldas',
            'SetKeywords' => 'Krajee, Yii2, Export, PDF, MPDF, Output, Privacy, Policy, yii2-mpdf',
        ]
    ]);
    return $pdf->render();
}
```

**View PDF:**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Empresa */

$this->title = $model->nombre_empresa;
?>
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'nombre_empresa',
            'foto',
            'telefono',
            'email:email',
            'natu_juridica',
            'limite_norte',
            'limite_sur',
            'limite_oriente',
            'limite_occidente',
            'n_suscriptores',
            'logo',
            'mision:ntext',
            'vision:ntext',
            'manual_funciones',
            'uso_agua',
            'tarifa_promedio',
            'periodo_cobro',
        ],
    ]) ?>
<h1><?= Html::encode('Tipo de Personal Contratado') ?></h1>
        <?php
foreach($model->personals as $personal){
    ?> 
        <?=DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $personal,
        'attributes' => [
            'area',
            'cantidad',
            'tipo_vinculacion',
            'observaciones:ntext',
        ],
    ]); 
}
?>
<h1><?= Html::encode('Personal Contratado') ?></h1>
<?php
foreach($model->integrantes as $integrante){
    ?> 
        <?=DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $integrante,
        'attributes' => [
            'nombre_integrante',
            'personal.area',
            'genero',
            'telefono',
        ],
    ]); 
}
?>
<h1><?= Html::encode('Información Financiera') ?></h1>
    <?php
foreach($model->financieros as $financiera){
    ?> 
        <?=DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $financiera,
        'attributes' => [
            'valor_facturado',
            'valor_recaudado',
            'cartera_morosa',
            'micromedicion',
            'concesion_agua',
            'fecha_concesion',
            'agente_contaminante:ntext',
            'proteccion_franja',
        ],
    ]); 
}
?>
<h1><?= Html::encode('Infraestructura Existente') ?></h1>
<?php
foreach($model->infraestructuras as $infraestructura){
    ?> 
        <?=DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $infraestructura,
        'attributes' => [
            'elemento',
            'cantidad',
            'material',
            'estado',
        ],
    ]); 
}
?>
<h1><?= Html::encode('Cobertura Acueducto') ?></h1>
<?php
foreach($model->coberturaas as $acueducto){
    ?> 
        <?=DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $acueducto,
        'attributes' => [
            'irca',
            'f_abastecedora',
            'con_servicio',
            'cal_servicio',
            'ver_benefi',
        ],
    ]); 
}
?>
<h1><?= Html::encode('Cobertura Alcantarillado') ?></h1>
<?php
foreach($model->coberturaals as $alcantarillado){
    ?> 
        <?=DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $alcantarillado,
        'attributes' => [
            'empresa_prestadora',
            'n_suscriptores',
            'f_receptora',
            'tratamiento_a_resi',
            'cobertura_r',
        ],
    ]); 
}
?>
<h1><?= Html::encode('Cobertura Aseo') ?></h1>
<?php
foreach($model->coberturaaseos as $aseo){
    ?> 
        <?=DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $aseo,
        'attributes' => [
            'empresa_prestadora',
            'n_suscriptores',
            'tipo_tratamiento',
            'sitio_dispo_final',
            'lugar_relleno',
            't_residuos_s_2016',
            't_residuos_s_2017',
            'cant_rutas',
            'f_barridos',
            'n_veces_recoleccion',
        ],
    ]); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola Michael para lo que necesitas te recomiendo que utilizes la libreria de Kartik ([aqui el link](http://demos.krajee.com/mpdf))  yo la he utilizado varias veces y funciona bastante bien , lo unico que tienes que hacer es crear una vista  , que sera tu pdf , y mandrle los modelos o datos que necesites , entonces en la vista presentas la informacion como mas desees y la libreria se encarga de transformar la vista a pdf .

Te copio aqui el ejemplo de como usar la libreria , tienes mas informacion en el la pagina web

```
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;


public function actionReport() {
    // get your HTML raw content without any layouts or scripts
   $yourDataModel=User::findOne(1);
   $moreDateToYourView=[1,2,4,5];

 $content = $this->renderPartial('_reportView',[
   'model'=>$yourDataModel,
   'data'=>$moreDateToYourView
 ]);


 // setup kartik\mpdf\Pdf component
 $pdf = new Pdf([
    // set to use core fonts only
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, 
    // A4 paper format
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4, 
    // portrait orientation
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT, 
    // stream to browser inline
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER, 
    // your html content input
    'content' => $content,  
    // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
    // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting 
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
    // any css to be embedded if required
    'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
     // set mPDF properties on the fly
    'options' => ['title' => 'Krajee Report Title'],
     // call mPDF methods on the fly
    'methods' => [ 
        'SetHeader'=>['Krajee Report Header'], 
        'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
    ]
]);

// return the pdf output as per the destination setting
return $pdf->render(); 
}
```

Comment: Buen dia gracias voy a intentar y comento, gracias

Comment: buen dia compañero @Enric hice lo que me indico pero me genero error, en una respuesta mas arriba muentro el error, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia hice lo que el compañero Enric Borrallo me indico pero me marca error anexo pantallazo y el codigo usado, ya el widget esta instalado

```
public function actionPdf(){     
    // get your HTML raw content without any layouts or scripts
    $content = $this->renderPartial('pdf1');

    // setup kartik\mpdf\Pdf component
    $pdf = new Pdf([
        // set to use core fonts only
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, 
        // A4 paper format
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4, 
        // portrait orientation
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT, 
        // stream to browser inline
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER, 
        // your html content input
        'content' => $content,  
        // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
        // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting 
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        // any css to be embedded if required
        'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
        // set mPDF properties on the fly
        'options' => ['title' => 'Krajee Report Title'],
        // call mPDF methods on the fly
        'methods' => [ 
            'SetHeader'=>['Krajee Report Header'], 
            'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
        ]
    ]);

    // return the pdf output as per the destination setting
    return $pdf->render(); 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has instalado el plugin ?? [  composer require  kartik-v/yii2-mpdf "dev-master"]   o añadelo a tu composer.json y ejecuta composer update o install. En la documentación del link . lee la parte de instalación.

Comment: Una vez instalado  importa la libreria al principio de tu controller con  ( use kartik\mpdf\Pdf; )

Comment: el error que te sale s debido a que no encuentra la classe Pdf , i eso es o porque no lo has instalado o porque no lo has importado la ruta en el controller

Comment: buen dia si ya lo corregi muchas gracias pero lo que no se ahora es como enlazar varios modelos en el mismo pdf, si debo crear un controller aparte a los de los modelos para el pdf o lo puedo hacer desde el controller que ya esta diseñado, gracias de antemano

Comment: Para enviar los modelos a tu vista que se trsnormara en pdf solo tienes que crearlos en el controller y luego los enviar en el parcial  render , tal y como puse en mi ejemplo las primeras lineas  

$this->renderPartial('_reportView',[
   'model'=>$yourDataModel,
   'modelo_dos'=>$model2
 ]);

Comment: favor de no usar la zona de respuestas para hacer aclaraciones de tu pregunta a quien te respondio, elimina esto, edita tu pregunta y colócalo ahí